# couldn't find file 'turbolinks' in Rails 4.0.4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, turbolinks

I just upgraded from Rails 3.2.17 to 4.0.4 and everything looks great. I copied over a lot of the config files from a brand new test 4.0.4 app I created. However, when I add in the following line to my `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file, I get an error:

```
//= require turbolinks
```

The error is:

```
couldn't find file 'turbolinks'
  (in /Users/scott/Code/ucode/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:15)
```

I want turbolinks. I'm on Rails 4.0.4. My test app didn't have this error. Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it? I also updated my `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` file to include:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have you added the `turbolinks` gem to your Gemfile?

```
gem 'turbolinks'
```

Comment: It happens! I'm glad I could help!

Comment: wow I can't believe that's been what I have been missing... @JoeKennedy thanks man

Comment: @TallPaul no problem, I'm glad I could help you out!